# Confusion in IP address configuration! Traceroute/pathping

Tags: ip, ip-address, isp, traceroute

When I query for my public IP address it obviously shows an IP address from Public cass typically `1.22.112.x`. I have a Dlink router which is configured to DHCP and I am guessing my router also gets internet edge IP from my ISP's DHCP server.

The webinterface of my router shows following configuration (for internet);
`IP : 10.25.x.x
subnet mask : 255.255.240.0`

> My first confusion is why the router gets an IP from again Private class?
>   How my router is able to route this private IP as they are not meant to be?

When I pathping google's DNS server this is the output i get

```
C:\Users\blahblah>pathping 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  Blahblah [192.168.0.102]
  1  192.168.0.1
  2  113.193.240.17
  3  115.111.205.13.static-mumbai.vsnl.net.in [115.111.205.13]
  4  172.31.33.189
  5  115.113.165.98.static-mumbai.vsnl.net.in [115.113.165.98]
  6  209.85.142.167
  7  216.239.41.155
  8  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
```

> Why i dont get an entry from 10.25.x.x series? My request should go from my router to the ISPs router and then to the internet. It should have an entry of ISPs default gateway(10.25.x.1).
>
> Lastly when we tracert/pathing an IP address lets say facebook/google, there's also no entry from network `1.x.x.x.` I typically get public IP from this series so should at least get an entry from this network as well.

FYI My ISP [Tikona Digital Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikona_Digital_Networks) has a centralized system where we're given an username and password. A user is required to login every time in order to access the internet. Secondly, all of the IP addresses are dynamic.

Comment: Forward and reverse routes can be different.

Comment: Your public IP address is the address of the WAN port of the NATting gateway closest to the web server which you use to determine it. Traceroute, however, may collect the IP addresses which it "sees coming from the other side", as already suggested in the above comment.

Comment: Apparently your ISP is employing [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) and each of your network operation can be affected by a tuple of things like IPs, Protocols and Ports,  so actually only your ISP can explain what network wizardry they have applied on your connections.  However if you can show the brand/model of your ISP's router we may be able to understand more.